# Is it possible to ssh to Google cloud linux vm using username and password

Tags: google-cloud-platform

It is possible to connect to Google linux VM using public and private key - however, is it possible to connect to the VM using username and password only. There is such a solution for linux VM on azure platform - is there anything similar on google cloud platform.
Thanks.

Comment: The same question but having a different context is asked [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101670/how-can-i-allow-ssh-password-authentication-from-only-certain-ip-addresses).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with the Google cloud, but if you have root access you can do anything you like.. It is simply to configure the ssh daemon to your wishes...

https://askubuntu.com/questions/101670/how-can-i-allow-ssh-password-authentication-from-only-certain-ip-addresses

**TL;DR**
Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` so it contains `PasswordAuthentication yes` and restart the ssh daemon.

The question is rather **should** you allow username and passwords? It is much more insecure.